# Range.offset with if and condition not working (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a code in VBA that are supposed to check if the cell background is a certain color and if so, do something. I have this line that keeps giving me an error

> "Object required".

I don't understand.. Is there anyone that could help me here?

```
 If r.Offset(0, 4 + i).Interior.color.RGB = RGB(155, 160, 167) Then
```

`r` is a `Range` and the argument is part of a `for each...` and the `i` is part of `for i= 1 to 3`.

Cheers,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need [`Interior.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color); remove the following `RGB`.

```
If r.Offset(0, 4 + i).Interior.Color = RGB(155, 160, 167) Then
```